# How to obtain a table of counts for criteria based on dates in R

Tags: r, date, count

Suppose I have a data frame with the following synthetic data:

```
> set.seed(1)
>
> patient_id = seq(101, 150)
> admit_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), as.Date('2021/01/10'), by="day"), 50, replace = T)
> release_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/11'), as.Date('2021/01/31'), by="day"), 50, replace = T)
> all = data.frame(patient_id, admit_date, release_date)
>
> all
     patient_id admit_date release_date
1           101 2021-01-03   2021-01-21
2           102 2021-01-04   2021-01-29
.
.
.
49          149 2021-01-08   2021-01-28
50          150 2021-01-07   2021-01-23
```

In the example above, the release date is after the admitted data.

I would like to **efficiently** create a table which counts the number of patients that are present on a given date?

I have the following solution which I would like to improve:

```
> date_range = sort(unique(c(all$admit_date, all$release_date)))
> count_vector = vector()
> 
> for(i in 1:length(date_range)){
>   current_date = date_range
>   count_vector[i] = length(which((all$admit_date <= date_range[i]) & 
>                                  (all$release_date >= date_range[i])) )
> }
> 
> date_count = data.frame(date_range, count_vector)
> date_count
   date_range count_vector
1  2021-01-01            3
2  2021-01-02            7
3  2021-01-03           12
.
.
.
27 2021-01-29            7
28 2021-01-30            2
29 2021-01-31            1
```

This solution is fine for small data sets, however is it possible to improve on my existing solution to efficiently obtain the counts required for large data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector with sequences of dates for each patient and pivot it (unnest):

```r
set.seed(1)
patient_id = seq(101, 150)
admit_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), 
                        as.Date('2021/01/10'), 
                        by="day"), 50, replace = T)
release_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/11'), 
                          as.Date('2021/01/31'), 
                          by="day"), 50, replace = T)
all = data.frame(patient_id, admit_date, release_date)

library(tidyverse)
date_pivot <- all %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(seq_dates = purrr::map2(admit_date, 
                                 release_date,
                                 function(x,y)
                                 seq(x,y, by = 1))) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(cols = seq_dates)
```

```
> date_pivot
# A tibble: 801 × 4
   patient_id admit_date release_date seq_dates 
        <int> <date>     <date>       <date>    
 1        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-05
 2        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-06
 3        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-07
 4        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-08
 5        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-09
 6        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-10
 7        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-11
 8        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-12
 9        101 2021-01-05 2021-01-22   2021-01-13
```

Then it's easier to count number of patients each day as it's one patient per day inline:

```r
count_dates <- date_pivot %>% 
  group_by(d_date = seq_dates) %>% 
  summarise(n_pat = n_distinct(patient_id))
```

```
> count_dates
# A tibble: 31 × 2
   d_date     n_pat
   <date>     <int>
 1 2021-01-01     3
 2 2021-01-02     6
 3 2021-01-03     9
 4 2021-01-04    13
 5 2021-01-05    19
 6 2021-01-06    25
 7 2021-01-07    31
 8 2021-01-08    34
 9 2021-01-09    42
```

This gives the same output as your code:

```r
> date_range = sort(unique(c(all$admit_date, all$release_date)))
> count_vector = vector()
> for(i in 1:length(date_range)){
+        current_date = date_range
+        count_vector[i] = length(which((all$admit_date <= date_range[i]) & 
+                                       (all$release_date >= date_range[i])) )
+      }
> count_vector[1:9]
[1]  3  6  9 13 19 25 31 34 42
```

You can take or not into account admit_date and release_date in your count:

```r
count_dates_inside_visit <- date_pivot %>% 
  filter(seq_dates > admit_date, seq_dates < release_date) %>% 
  group_by(d_date = seq_dates) %>% 
  summarise(n_pat = n_distinct(patient_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two datasets with fuzzyjoin on range and `count` occurrence of each date.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

date_range = sort(unique(c(all$admit_date, all$release_date)))

data.frame(date_range) %>%
  fuzzy_inner_join(all, 
                    by = c('date_range' = 'admit_date', 
                           'date_range' = 'release_date'), 
                    match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  count(date_range)

#   date_range  n
#1  2021-01-01  3
#2  2021-01-02  6
#3  2021-01-03  9
#4  2021-01-04 13
#5  2021-01-05 19
#6  2021-01-06 25
#7  2021-01-07 31
#8  2021-01-08 34
#9  2021-01-09 42
#10 2021-01-10 50
#11 2021-01-11 50
#...
#...
```